# How to improve rand from pgfmath in tkz-euclide?

Tags: pgfmath, tkz-euclide

I make this minimal file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-8,xmax=8,ymin=-7,ymax=7]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\pgfmathsetmacro{\avect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\evect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hvect}{{int(rand * 8)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ivect}{{int(rand * 7)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\jvect}{{int(rand * 7)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kvect}{{int(rand * 7)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lvect}{{int(rand * 6)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mvect}{{int(rand * 6)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nvect}{{int(rand * 5)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ovect}{{int(rand * 7)}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pvect}{{int(rand * 7)}}
\tkzDefPoint(\avect,\ivect){A}
\tkzDefPoint(\bvect,\jvect){B}
\tkzDefPoint(\cvect,\kvect){C}
\tkzDefPoint(\dvect,\lvect){D}
\tkzDefPoint(\evect,\mvect){E}
\tkzDefPoint(\fvect,\nvect){F}
\tkzDefPoint(\gvect,\ovect){G}
\tkzDefPoint(\hvect,\pvect){H}
\tkzDefPoint(\ivect,\avect){I}
\tkzDefPoint(\jvect,\bvect){J}
\tkzDefPoint(\kvect,\cvect){K}
\tkzDefPoint(\lvect,\dvect){L}
\tkzDefPoint(\mvect,\evect){M}
\tkzDefPoint(\nvect,\fvect){N}
\tkzDefPoint(\ovect,\gvect){O}
\tkzDefPoint(\pvect,\hvect){P}
\tkzDrawSegments[->,line width=2pt](A,B C,D E,F G,H I,J K,L M,N O,P)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the results is:

[image]

How can I automate, so that more vectors can enter?

Comment: What do you mean by automating? How many vectors do you need? What does that have to do with the `rand` function?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I try to use "for in range" loop for automating. The rand function needs `\pgfmathsetmacro` for record the rand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need more than 26 points, you're going to want to use a number for the points' names. (The `\foreach` macro would allow `\foreach \pnt in {A,...,P}`.)

Here I'm using three `\foreach` loops:

1. to define the points – instead of using `\pgfmathsetmacro` (or rather `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`) we just use the `randint` function of the [`xfp` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp) that apparently is used by `tkz` internally.

   Or we use the `evaluate` key from the `\foreach` macro (which uses PGFmath):

   ```
   \foreach \pnt[
     evaluate={\xVal=random(-8,8);
               \yVal=random(-7,7);}] in {1,...,50} {
     \tkzDefPoint(\xVal, \yVal){pnt-\pnt}
   }
   ```
2. to draw the segments.
3. to label the points – since all points are named `pnt-<num>` now we can't use `\tkzLabelPoints` since that wouldn't look good. Instead we use the more explicit version `\tkzLabelPoint` where we can specify a custom label text.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-8,xmax=8,ymin=-7,ymax=7]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
%\foreach \pnt in {1,...,50} {
%  \tkzDefPoint({{randint(-8,8)},{randint(-7,7)}}){pnt-\pnt}
%}
\foreach \pnt[
  evaluate={\xVal=random(-8,8);
            \yVal=random(-7,7);}] in {1,...,50} {
  \tkzDefPoint(\xVal, \yVal){pnt-\pnt}
}
\foreach \pnt[evaluate={\pntNext=\pnt+1;}] in {1,3,...,49} {
  \tkzDrawSegments[->,line width=2pt](pnt-\pnt,pnt-\pntNext)
}
\foreach \pnt in {1,...,50} {
  \tkzLabelPoint(pnt-\pnt){$p_{\pnt}$}
}

% vanilla TikZ alternative:
%\foreach \pnt in {1,...,50}
%  \coordinate (pnt-\pnt) at ({random(-8,8)},{random(-7,7)});
%
%\foreach \pnt[evaluate={\pntNext=\pnt+1;}] in {1,3,...,49}
%  \draw[->,line width=2pt](pnt-\pnt) -- (pnt-\pntNext);
%
%\foreach \pnt in {1,...,50}
%  \node[below] at (pnt-\pnt) {$p_{\pnt}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With a little bit work we can do everything in one loop but this way, we could `fill=white` in the last loop so that all labels aren't covered by the lines.